# Pyocrypt DES3 file encryption, decryption missing sections of text

Tags: python, encryption, io, des

I'm using a 3DES encryption from this [blog](https://www.laurentluce.com/posts/python-and-cryptography-with-pycrypto/) (under header *Applications*) in python with [Crypto](https://sourceforge.net/projects/cryptopy/), And I've been testing it on the [Tree of Fun Files](https://github.com/GiovanniMoretti/159251-directoryTreeOfFunFiles), as an example for this question the [An Accountant and his Frog.txt](https://github.com/GiovanniMoretti/159251-directoryTreeOfFunFiles/blob/master/An%20Accountant%20and%20his%20Frog.txt) among many other files (file size varies greatly, for example [TOASTERS](https://github.com/GiovanniMoretti/159251-directoryTreeOfFunFiles/blob/master/TOASTERS.TXT)).

**pyencrypt**

```
import os
from Crypto.Cipher import DES3

def encrypt_file(in_filename, out_filename, chunk_size, key, iv):
    des3 = DES3.new(key, DES3.MODE_CFB, iv)
    with open(in_filename, 'r') as in_file:
        with open(out_filename, 'w') as out_file:
            while True:
                chunk = in_file.read(chunk_size)
                if len(chunk) == 0:
                    break
                elif len(chunk) % 16 != 0:
                    chunk += ' ' * (16 - len(chunk) % 16)
                out_file.write(des3.encrypt(chunk))

def decrypt_file(in_filename, out_filename, chunk_size, key, iv):
    des3 = DES3.new(key, DES3.MODE_CFB, iv)

    with open(in_filename, 'r') as in_file:
        with open(out_filename, 'w') as out_file:
            while True:
                chunk = in_file.read(chunk_size)
                if len(chunk) == 0:
                    break
                out_file.write(des3.decrypt(chunk))
```

**Usage**

```
import pyencrypt, md5
from Crypto import Random
iv = Random.get_random_bytes(8)
m = md5.new()
m.update("encryptionkey")
key =  m.digest()
.encrypt_file("C:\\treeoffunfiles\\Accountant and his frog.txt", 'C:\\treeoffun\\to_enc.enc', 8192, key, iv)
pyencrypt.decrypt_file('C:\\treeoffunfiles\\to_enc.enc', 'C:\\treeoffunfiles\\to_enc.dec', 8192, key, iv)
```

And the encryption of files is great (no complaints there)! but the [decryption](http://pastebin.com/s4CmJC5y) of the file isn't as great. Here is an [comparison](https://www.diffnow.com/v1?report=m8hzi) output between the original file and the decrypted file from [notepad++](https://sourceforge.net/projects/npp-compare/).

[image: notepad++]
<sub>(source: [iforce.co.nz](http://iforce.co.nz/i/3qnyhvzf.b5w.png))</sub>

Any ideas on why the decrypted file is missing content from the original? and how can I make the decryption (and encryption if necessary) more accurate (across files that may vary in size)?

Comment: What is the 8192 about? What happens if you use 16384?

Comment: As far as I can see the Chunk_size is only used for the python readin and therefore reads 8192 Byte from input? What happens if you have a longer input file?

Comment: the result with `16384` comes out like [this](http://www.diffnow.com/?report=g94bz) _better_ but still no cigar.

Comment: This works for me, but then I'm not on Windows.  Could you open the files in binary mode ("rb"/"wb") instead and see if that helps?

Comment: @DSM that works great, heres the [result](http://www.diffnow.com/?report=vdtrs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The suggested answer was posted in the comments by [DSM](https://stackoverflow.com/users/487339/dsm) (I've been waiting for him to post answer, this can stay for the meantime).

> This works for me, but then I'm not on Windows. Could you open the files in binary mode ("rb"/"wb") instead and see if that helps? – DSM

The problem was that the original implementation of the 3DES encryption was ran on a `unix` machine. Whereas the results on a `windows` system differ.

In order to fix the `chunks` of missing data, DSM suggested to change the file input/output to binary instead of regular reading/writting, which has given the desired output as seen [here](http://www.diffnow.com/?report=vdtrs).

fyi diffnow only stores the results for 1 month.